# Same Package - Multiple Repos

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

Which repository will Ubuntu choose to download a package from if the same package is available in more than one repos? Suppose a package A was initially installed from repository X and later I added repo Y which also has package A. Which repo will be chosen to update the package? Also if I completely remove this package and try to reinstall then which repo would be preferred by Ubuntu to install the package?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, the package with the highest version number is installed, regardless of which repository it comes from, *unless* its version number is lower than the currently installed version of the package (this can happen, for example, if you downloaded a higher version as a `.deb` package and installed it manually). In the very unlikely case that several repositories have the same (highest) version of a package, the package is installed from the one which appears first in the `sources.list` file.

You can change this, however, by assigning a different *priority* to some packages based on various criteria. The previous paragraph is true with the default settings because by default all packages have priority 500. If different versions of the package have different priorities, however, the version with the highest priority will be installed, and version numbers will only be used as tie-breakers if several versions have the same (highest) priority. Also, if the highest-priority package has priority at least 1000, it will be installed even if its version is lower than the version currently installed.

Priorities are managed in `/etc/apt/preferences` and documented in `man apt_preferences`. See my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170079/update-single-package-from-ubuntu-utopic-unicorn-when-running-trusty-tahr/170100#170100) for an example of how they can be used.

Comment: Note that the documentation says that it assigns a priority of 990 _to the versions that belong to the target release._ So not 500 as you say here (_because by default all packages have priority 500._) It is 500 only if it is not the proper target.

Comment: @AlexisWilke By default, there is no target release.