# List all packages available (and/or installed) from a specific source

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, ppa, repository

How can I list all package names and their versions available from a specific package source (official repositories, PPAs or other repositories) ?

Also, how can I filter only the installed packages from that list?
If one version of a package is available from the queried source, but the installed version is from anywhere else, it should not appear in the output.

Comment: You've done it again! This is like the 3rd time you've posted a question I've been meaning to post for a while! :D

Comment: Not sure about the first question but for the last question [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/729192/462484) might help.

Comment: @7_R3X No, I don't care to which version a package would get upgraded, I only want to get a list of packages that is currently installed from a specific software source.

Comment: @ByteCommander : How about you comment all other repos in source.list, `apt-get update` and then `apt-cache dump` ? It should work as dump lists all the packages available. Not sure though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list all packages I've installed from a particular PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5976/how-can-i-list-all-packages-ive-installed-from-a-particular-ppa)

Comment: Also, probably: http://serverfault.com/questions/138546/in-ubuntu-linux-how-do-i-list-packages-installed-from-the-universe-repository, http://superuser.com/questions/132346/find-packages-installed-from-a-certain-repository-with-aptitude

Comment: @muru: Yes, I thought this question looked familiar! I think I didn't ask myself because I found those.

Comment: @muru: Your linked question only deals with *installed* packages from that source, not *all* packages available from it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster the command line methods are rather easily extended.

Comment: How about `apt list --installed | grep wily-security` ?